# How to console.log the content of a closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I would like to see the content of a closure in JavaScript.

In the following code, I would like to see the *closure* of the function `closure_f` returned by the anonymous function. The local scope of the anonymous function must be stored somewhere, I would like to see where it is stored. How can this be done in Node or in the browser?

```
var closure_F = (function(){
var info = "info-string";
var f1 = function(){
    console.log(info);
};
return f1;
}());

closure_F(); // logs 'info-string' as expected.
console.log(closure_F); // This did not provide any valuable information.
```

Comment: Add a `debugger` statement, then step through the code.

Comment: Do a `console.dir(closure_F)` in Chrome and look at `[[Scopes]]`.

Comment: What runtime do you use? In Chrome devtools you *can* inspect the closure environment of a logged function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The local scope of the anonymous function must be stored somewhere

That's an implementation detail of the JavaScript runtime. It isn't stored anywhere that is exposed to the JavaScript program.

> How can this be done in Node or in the browser?

Dedicated debugging tools can inspect the data there. Set a breakpoint on the `console.log` call.

Note that optimisations mean that only variables used within the returned function will be visible.

Answer (score 9):

**WAY 1: Internal property `[[Scope]]`**

You can modify your code by adding `console.dir` and then run it in the **Chrome Dev Console**:

```
var closure_F = (function(){
  var info = "info-string";
  var f1 = function(){
    console.log(info);
  };

  return f1;
}());

closure_F();
console.dir(closure_F); 
// console.dir prints all the properties of a specified JavaScript object
```

If you open the console you will see that it prints all the properties of the object (function), including the internal property `[[Scopes]]`.

This internal property `[[Scopes]]` will contain any surrounding scopes of the `closure_f`, and its closure. See example:

[image: Scope internal property containing the Closure]

**Note:** `[[Scope]]` is an internal implementation of JS and cannot be programatically accessed within the program.

**WAY 2: Setting a breakpoint - `debugger`**

Another way to see the *Closure* of a function is to add a `debugger` statement and create a break point in the function who's closure you want to inspect.
As an example you can run this in the console:

```
function createClosure (){

  var secret = "shhhhh";

  return function inner(){
    debugger;
    console.log(secret);
  };
  
};

var innerFunction = createClosure();

innerFunction();
```

[www.ecma-international.org](https://www.ecma-international.org)  >>   [[[Scope]]](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)   >>  Table 9